# Tkinter tray icon (winico, twapi, pywin32)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning tkinter but get disappointed about the lack of a tray handling feature. So far, I found some tcl extensions: **winico** http://wiki.tcl.tk/4089 and **twapi** http://wiki.tcl.tk/9886
Unfortunately, I lack the ability to make python/c/tcl wrappers (if anyone know that can help ñ_ñ)
Also I found pywin32 and write a little tray/console app, but I don't know how to use it with tkinter (it freezes the tk() window).
However, I prefer to use extension instead of the windows api.

Answer (score 1):

Is this [mailing list message](http://www.mail-archive.com/tkinter-discuss@python.org/msg01939.html) any help?

### Edit with comment from @FelipeJavierV.H.:

So I contacted [Michael Lange](http://klappnase.bubble.org/) and he shared with me a wrapper he wrote for `winico`/`tktray`:

1. Download [winico](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tktable/files/winico/).
2. Unzip the `winico` folder in the `tcl` folder of your Python installation (e.g. `C:\Programas\Python25\tcl\winico0.6\`. Note: a lot of files inside, `demo.tcl`, `pkgIndex.tcl`, `Winico06.dll`).
3. Download [this program](http://klappnase.bubble.org/bscallmon/index.html), extract it and execute `TrayIcon.py` (maybe with a `smiley.ico` in the same folder).

Comment: `So I contacted Michael Lange (http://klappnase.bubble.org/) and he shared with me a wrapper he wrote for winico/tktray:

download winico:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tktable/files/winico/

unzip the winico folder in the tcl folder of your python installation:
C:\Programas\Python25\tcl\winico0.6\ <= (a lot of files inside, demo.tcl, pkgIndex.tcl, Winico06.dll)

download this program:
http://klappnase.bubble.org/bscallmon/index.html

extract it and execute 'TrayIcon.py' (maybe with a smiley.ico in the same folder)

enjoy ñ_ñ`

Comment: It seems bubble.org (linked to in step 3) no longer exists.

Comment: It's in _the_ archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20120428000009/http://klappnase.bubble.org/bscallmon/index.html